# Why the default windows 8 universal app created in VS 2015 has a dark background

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, win-universal-app, windows-8.1-universal

I'm creating a windows 8 universal app using C# in Visual Studio 2015. I followed this path to create an empty project: Visual C#->Windows->Windows 8->Universal->Blank App(Universal Windows 8.1).

I'm surprised to find out that the empty app start with black background and white foreground. Is there any particular reason why Microsoft does this?

[image]

Also, is there any elegant way to change the background and foreground color? I was able to do it by changing the following config in the MainPage.xaml file:

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}"></Grid>
```

To:

```
<Grid Background="White"></Grid>
```

**But I wasn't able to change the foreground, and if I add a button to the window, the button text cannot be seen on a white background because the button foreground is white.** (As far as I know, all the children components will inherit the background color or the foreground color depending all what kind of components they are.)

Any clarification is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the Remarks on the [Application.RequestedTheme property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.application.requestedtheme) on MSDN:

> There are two built in themes: "Light" and "Dark". By default your app
>   runs using the "Dark" theme (in the themeresources.xaml file, the key
>   name for the "Dark" resources is "Default"). You can set the app's
>   **RequestedTheme** property to specify which theme is used.

So setting

```
<Application ... RequestedTheme="Light">
```

in your App.xaml makes your application use the Light theme.